# Signalling game with multiple signal

Tags: game-theory, asymmetric-information, signaling

I am solving a signaling game where the manufacturer has private information about its production capacity. It can signal it using the wholesale price or limiting the order quantity of the buyer. Have you seen a paper or research using two signal, (in my case wholesale price and order limit)
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like a standard signaling game, so you are not likely to find something as specific in a research paper. Maybe, I am missing something, but have you tried standard techniques to solve a signaling game with a costly signal?

Comment: Thanks, Regio! Yes here the problem is the signal can come from two sources either the wholesale price or selling limit. I dod not see 2D signal anywhere

Comment: I recommend you edit the question so that you present the complete model description: Players, preferences, action sets, timing, and information sets. 

Then add an explanation of what have you tried, or what part is confusing to you. Many people here will be able to point you in the right direction or solve your question directly. I cannot see how having a 2D signal is much harder than having a 1D signal. f you could present the complete model, it will be easier to see the main hurdles.

Comment: Thanks Regio, I asked a new question

Comment: Clarification and answers to this question can be  found here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/36168/signalling-game-multiple-signals